# How to set different colors to drawable in a loop

Tags: android, colors

First I am creating dynamic imagview in a loop then setting background image, after that I am taking drawable and using the following code to set color to my imageview drawable,

```
int[] colorcodes = {Color.BLUE, Color.BLACK, Color.GREEN};
for (int i = 0; i < medicine.size(); i++) {
    ImageView image = new ImageView(getActivity());
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(60, 60);
    params.setMargins(10, 20, 10, 20);
    image.setLayoutParams(params);

    colorOfMedicine = medicineDetails.getMedicineColor();

    image.setBackgroundResource(0);
    image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_tablet);
   //Drawable drawable = image.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tablet);
    Drawable drawable = image.getBackground();
    drawable.clearColorFilter();
    //image.invalidate();
    //image.setBackgroundColor(colorcodes[i]);

    drawable.setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(colorcodes[i], PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
    layout.addView(image);
}
```

But my problem is, it is setting last color to all the image.

Comment: what is the problem you are facing??

Comment: Only last color is setting to all the drawables.

Comment: can u post some code, so that it is easy to understand?

Comment: paste your entire loop please

Comment: Here Green Color is setting to all drawable

Comment: Setting color filter to your `drawable` will do nothing to your `image`.

Comment: you have to `mutate()` your drawable

Comment: How to  mutate() drawable and what is the use of that?

Comment: how to mutate() drawable? by calling `Drawable#mutate()` method

Comment: @pskink mutate() is working fine. Thank you